# How can I disable the "Help" key under OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I like to use the "Del" key when I type, but often miss and hit the "Help" key by mistake, which can be costly (another window opens, sometimes steals the focus, etc.). I'd like a software solution such that hitting the Help key does nothing.

Yes, I've tried remapping it.

There are a ton of resources around on how to rebind keys under OSX, but I've yet to find anything that can affect the "Help" key -- it seems to work outside the normal flow.

Is there a way to just plain make it not work (other than ripping off the key and covering the contact underneath with something non-conductive)?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm talking about the key labeled 'help' on a full-size Mac keyboard, next to the 'home' key and above the 'delete' key, sitting in a vertical line with the left-arrow key (below) and the F14 key (above).

Comment: None of my Apple keyboards have a "Help" key at all. Can you give a little more description of the keyboard in question? My Apple kbrds have the Del key surrounded by (CCW from 12 o'clock) Eject F12 = ] and \

Comment: Have you tried prying it off with a screwdriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved, using http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/. It offers only set mappings, but one of them is to turn Help into F13 (which does nothing at the moment) so I'm set.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to tweak how keys are triggered in OSX is through Quicksilver:

http://quicksilver.en.softonic.com/mac

It's an application launcher, but it's extremely extensible and one of the things you can add are global hotkeys. You could probably set one up to do nothing (or perhaps something useful!) when Help is pressed, I think I did this to remap capslock on my old iBook.

A word of caution: I haven't used a Mac in years (since Tiger) and I heard Quicksilver's developer abandonned it — so I'm not sure this will still work and can't test it myself. Nonetheless, QS is pretty slick and you might find other uses for it as well...

Good luck!